# MSSQL Server working on RH9 or Centos9

Tags: linux, permissions, unix, file-permissions, sql

Has anybody running mssql-server on RH9 or Centos9?

I got this Error when trying to setup:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.2 (Plow)
Capturing core dump and information to /var/opt/mssql/log...
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal', 'wheel' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
      Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal', 'wheel' can see all messages.
      Pass -q to turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.
tail: cannot open '/var/log/messages' for reading: Permission denied
Wed May 31 07:20:03 AM CEST 2023 Capturing program information
Wed May 31 07:20:03 AM CEST 2023 Attempting to capture a dump with paldumper for pid 47418
WARNING: Capture attempt failure detected
Attempting to capture a filtered dump with paldumper for pid 47418
Captured a filtered dump with paldumper
Wed May 31 07:20:04 AM CEST 2023 Capturing program binaries
/usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/share/Pegasus/scripts’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/share/empty.sshd’: Permission denied
/usr/bin/find: ‘/usr/libexec/initscripts/legacy-actions/auditd’: Permission denied
Wed May 31 07:20:04 AM CEST 2023 Compressing the dump files
Core dump and information are being compressed in the background. When
complete, they can be found in the following location:
  /var/opt/mssql/log/core.sqlservr.05_31_2023_07_20_02.47418.tbz2
Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.
```

Comment: `Initial setup of Microsoft SQL Server failed. Please consult the ERRORLOG
in /var/opt/mssql/log for more information.` Seems like it might have some pertinent information.

Comment: lots of "Permission denied" in that output - at first glance, it seems you may have a Permission issue

Comment: Reason: 0x00000004
        Message: RETAIL ASSERT: Expression=(NT_SUCCESS(status)) File=drtl.cpp Line=1550
        Process: 47418 - sqlservr
         Thread: 47423 (application thread 0x8)
    Instance Id: 4ab672e2-582e-4ffb-86ee-a98de6ca8aa5
       Crash Id: 03084f4d-ae41-481b-8d19-f1b5f3656882
    Build stamp: 64d84bb0bc9c70fe33133ed567aac343d1cb7d33d6acfc35b9aca9b81fac9c77
   Distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9.2 (Plow)
     Processors: 8
   Total Memory: 24852033536 bytes
      Timestamp: Wed May 31 07:20:02 2023
     Last errno: 13
Last errno text: Permission denied

Comment: Thatś all what I can see in log file

Comment: Have you tried installed as root or `sudo` by chance on this system. Anything interesting in the OS level `/var/log/messages` logs. If you are running SELinux, might have to disable it too so talk with your Red Hat sysadmin experts (or vendor support) if needed too for other reasons why. I say start with installing as root login or sudo just in case since things indicate permission issues.